# WordPress + JavaScipt + AJAX + MySQL: insert query for form

Tags: plugins, ajax, javascript, mysql

I'm trying to make booking - plugin with form on WordPress-admin site, where I can add new event in calendar (made with JavaScript).
I have to submit form with all data and insert data to MySQL Database.

My **ajax.js** file:

```
function ajaxSubmit(e){
var nazwa_szkolenia = document.getElementById("nazwa_szkolenia").value;
var Data_szkolenia = document.getElementById("Data_szkolenia").value;
var Godzina = document.getElementById("Godzina").value;
var Max_pacjent = document.getElementById("Max_pacjent").value;

// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
var dataString = 'nazwa_szkolenia1=' + nazwa_szkolenia + '&Data_szkolenia1=' + Data_szkolenia + '&Godzina1=' + Godzina + '&Max_pacjent1=' + Max_pacjent;
if (nazwa_szkolenia == '' || Data_szkolenia == '' || Max_pacjent == '') {
    alert("fill all fields");
} else {
    // prevent the default action.
    e.preventDefault();

    var myform= jQuery(this).serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        // Get the admin ajax url which we have passed through wp_localize_script().
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
        action: "submitAjaxForm",
        data: dataString,
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){                                        
        console.error("The following error occurred: " + textStatus, errorThrown);                                                       
    },
        success:function(data){
            alert("process OK");
        }
    });
}
return false;
}
```

**arcode-functions.php**:

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'registerFormAction');

    function registerFormAction(){
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submitAjaxForm','submitAjaxForm_callback');
        add_action('wp_ajax_submitAjaxForm','submitAjaxForm_callback');

    }
    
    function submitAjaxForm_callback(){
        global $wpdb;
    
      
        $nazwa_szkolenia2 = $_POST['nazwa_szkolenia1'];
        $Data_szkolenia2 = $_POST['Data_szkolenia1'];
        $Godzina2 = $_POST['Godzina1'];
        $Max_pacjent2 = $_POST['Max_pacjent1'];
    
    
        $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->modul_terminarz, array( 'proba' => $nazwa_szkolenia2, 'id' => '10', 'data_szkolenia' => $Data_szkolenia2, 'typ_szkolenia' => '1', 'ile_miejsc' => $Max_pacjent2, 'pelne' => '1', 'Ile_miejsc_akt' => '4' ) );
   

        wp_die();
    }

?>
```

I've added `admin-ajax.php` with `wp_localize_script` function. The form button is made with JavaScript:

```
var Input_Form_Send = document.createElement('input');
    Input_Form_Send.value = 'Utwórz';
    Input_Form_Send.type = 'submit';
    Input_Form_Send.className = 'input-form-send';  
    Input_Form_Send.onclick = ajaxSubmit;
```

When I fill all fields from form, click on the button, then comes alert "process ok", but on the Database comes nothing new... *nazwa_szkolenia*, *Data_szkolenia*, *Godzina*, *Max_pacjent* -those are the names of the form fields.

Maybe you know what I've made wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you serialize the data with jQuery but don't pass that variable via AJAX? My guess is the data needs to be in array from, not a string of data like a URL.

You could verify if the data gets to the AJAX callback function by returning a data value and displaying it in the `alert()` in the success function.

What works for me is to put the data in a relational array and use `GET` instead of post.

```
var dataString = [];
dataString['nazwa_szkolenia1'] = nazwa_szkolenia;  // etc.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't serialize data as you see - code was before copierd from another function. I've made like you said - it didn't work...I've add also return for data in alert for succes, but it gives "0"... where it should be string success or error...

Comment: Just before `wp_die()` try echoing a static string, like `echo "AJAX is working";` This debug should confirm that AJAX is working. If you're still getting 0, then I would guess you're using the wrong hook to register the `submitAjaxForm` action.

Comment: The next debugging step is to make sure the data is being sent to the database. In my system, I have to create the SQL query, but it's easy to debug: I just echo the query to check for syntax mistakes. I do note that you always set the `id` of the record to `10`. If you need it to create a new record, shouldn't that value auto-increment?

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned everything a little bit. Now it looks like that:

**ajax.js**

```
function ajaxSubmit(e){
var nazwa_szkolenia = document.getElementById("nazwa_szkolenia").value;
var Data_szkolenia = document.getElementById("Data_szkolenia").value;
var Godzina = document.getElementById("Godzina").value;
var Max_pacjent = document.getElementById("Max_pacjent").value;

var dataString = [];
dataString['nazwa_szkolenia1'] = nazwa_szkolenia;
dataString['Data_szkolenia1'] = Data_szkolenia;
dataString['Godzina1'] = Godzina;
dataString['Max_pacjent1'] = Max_pacjent;

if (nazwa_szkolenia == '' || Data_szkolenia == '' || Godzina == '' || Max_pacjent == '') {
alert("Wypełnij wszystkie pola");
} else {
    // prevent the default action.
    e.preventDefault();

    //var myform= jQuery(this).serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        // Get the admin ajax url which we have passed through wp_localize_script().
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
        action: "submitAjaxForm",
        data: dataString,
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){                                        
        console.error("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);                                                       
    },
        success:function(data){
console.log(dataString);
        }
    });
}
return false;
}
```

**arcode-functions.php:**

```
<?php

function registerFormAction(){
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submitAjaxForm','submitAjaxForm_callback');
    add_action('wp_ajax_submitAjaxForm','submitAjaxForm_callback');
}
    
function submitAjaxForm_callback(){
   global $wpdb;
    
    $nazwa_szkolenia2 = $_GET['nazwa_szkolenia1'];
    $Data_szkolenia2 = $_GET['Data_szkolenia1'];
    $Godzina_szkolenia2 = $_GET['Godzina1'];
    $Max_pacjent2 = $_GET['Max_pacjent1'];

        $result = $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->modul_terminarz, array( 
                                  'Nazwa_szkolenia' => $nazwa_szkolenia2, 
                                  'Data_szkolenia' => $Data_szkolenia2, 
                                  'Godzina_szkolenia' => $Godzina_szkolenia2,
                                  'Typ_szkolenia' => '1',
                                  'Ile_miejsc_max' => $Max_pacjent2,
                                  'Pelna_obsada' => '0',
                                  ) );

    wp_die();   
}


add_action('init', 'registerFormAction');

?>
```

that code stays in my **menu.php**:

```
// Hook for adding admin menus

 add_action('admin_menu', 'create_Terminarz_menu');
 
 // action function for above hook
 
/**
 * Adds a new top-level page to the administration menu.
 */
function create_Terminarz_menu() {

     add_menu_page(
        'ARCode Terminarz',
        'Terminarz',
        'manage_options',
        'zarzadzanie-terminami',
        'tm_zarzadzanie_terminami_odp',
        plugins_url('images/terminarz.png', __FILE__),'2.2.10'
    );
    
     add_submenu_page( 'zarzadzanie-terminami', 'ARCode Terminarz' . 'Terminy szkoleń', '<b style="color:#E46500;">Terminy szkoleń</b>', 'manage_options', 'zarzadzanie-terminami', 'tm_zarzadzanie_terminami_odp');
     add_submenu_page( 'zarzadzanie-terminami', 'ARCode Terminarz' . 'Pacjenci', 'Pacjenci', 'manage_options', 'pacjenci', 'tm_zarzadzanie_pacjentami_odp');
      add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','load_custom_wp_admin_js');
}

/**
 * Display callback for the Unsub page.
 */
 function tm_zarzadzanie_pacjentami_odp() {
     
 }
 
 
 
 function load_custom_wp_admin_js($hook){
    wp_register_script( 'jquery.min.js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'kalendarz',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'kalendarz.css',false,'1.1','all' );
    wp_register_script( 'ajax-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'ajax_js.js');
    wp_localize_script('ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'ajax_js.js');
}

 
 /**
 * Display callback for the Unsub page.
 */
 function tm_zarzadzanie_terminami_odp() {
     include_once( 'arcode-functions.php');
     include_once( 'kalendarz.php');
     
     ?>
     <div class="wrap" style="position: fixed;
          width: 85%;
          top: 40px;
          bottom: 80px;">
     </div>
     <?php

 }
```

In **kalendarz.php** I have all functions for booking calendar and forms, this is the form which I need to send:

```
this.createFormular = function () {
             var ob = this.o;
             
             var Admin_Form = document.createElement('form')
             Admin_Form.name='Formularz_Admin';
             Admin_Form.method='GET';
             Admin_Form.action='';

             var tabela = document.createElement('table');
             tabela.className = 'formular-table';
            
             var tr = document.createElement('tr');
             tabela.appendChild(tr);
             var td = document.createElement('td');
             td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Nazwa szkolenia:   '));
             tr.appendChild(td);
             tr.appendChild(td);
             
             td.appendChild(Input_Name_Training);
             
             var tr = document.createElement('tr');
             tabela.appendChild(tr);
             var td = document.createElement('td');
             td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Data szkolenia:   '));
             tr.appendChild(td);
             tr.appendChild(td);
             
             td.appendChild(Input_Date_Training);
             
             var tr = document.createElement('tr');
             tabela.appendChild(tr);
             var td = document.createElement('td');
             td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Godzina szkolenia:   '));
             tr.appendChild(td);
             tr.appendChild(td);
             
             td.appendChild(Input_Hour_Training);
             
             var tr = document.createElement('tr');
             tabela.appendChild(tr);
             var td = document.createElement('td');
             td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Max ilość osób:   '));
             tr.appendChild(td);
             tr.appendChild(td);
             
             td.appendChild(Input_How_Many_People);          
             
             
             var tr = document.createElement('tr');
             tabela.appendChild(tr);
             var td = document.createElement('td');
             td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('   '));
             tr.appendChild(td);
             tr.appendChild(td);
             
             td.appendChild(Input_Form_Send);       
              
             Admin_Form.appendChild(tabela);
             
             this.divForm.appendChild(Admin_Form);
             

         };
```

I've tried to check if `submitAjaxForm`is working, I've checked it with echo as scott said, but it gives nothing. DataString gives right Array, but data gives 0...
I don't know what I make wrong ;/ I don't see if hook to register for submitAjaxForm is bad, in my opinion all hooks are ok...?